# Offered job but still awaiting contract

Tags: new-job

Last Thursday I had a 2nd interview with a company where during the interview they told me that i got the job and discussed the financial package / benefits. After I agreed to the package offered to me by the company the interviewer told me that on Friday I will receive a copy of the contract via email.

I waited the whole day but I never received this mail. On Monday I decided that I should call to see whether they have the correct details. The interviewer told me that the HR person is on maternity leave and she's working from home; but he stated that he will try to send them to me on Monday afternoon. At the very end of the conversation he told me that he didn't forget about me!

Today is Thursday and the mail hasn't come in yet - what do you think guys? I am worried and at the same time I am excited to start this new job.

Comment: Because you don't have anything in writing it is a good idea to keep applying, and interviewing.

Comment: Let the interviewer know that HR hasn't contacted you. As a mater of due diligence, check your Spam box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Today is Thursday and the mail hasn't come in yet - what do you think
>   guys ?

Since you got an offer (including financial details) and accepted, it's almost certainly just a delay in the paperwork that is holding things up. With summer vacations, and in your case with an HR person on maternity leave, these things sometimes take long than expected. Try not to worry.

The general expectation seems to be to wait at least a week between communications.

You spoke with them on Monday. I would wait until next Monday afternoon, see if you have received your contract yet, and contact them again if not.

Comment: Will try not to worry then, whilst hoping to receive the contract soon! Thanks for for your reply.